# Question marked duplicate of deleted question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-questions

[This question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/5128/3955) has been marked as a duplicate of [this one](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/5108/what-song-is-playing-in-background), but the target question happens to be deleted. This is not a useful situation, so I request that

- either the deleted question be undeleted (if it deserves to be undeleted), or
- the closed question be unmarked as a duplicate.

(Please note that I don't have enough reputation to actually view the deleted question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and re-opened it, but given that the other question was marked as "dead" I wouldn't get my hopes up for an answer.

Comment: Closed due to inactivity, and no answers.